# Write a query to find the students with the same first name AND last name?

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

So here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT A.STUDENT_ID
FROM STUDENT A, STUDENT B
WHERE A.FNAME=B.FNAME
    AND A.LNAME=B.LNAME
    AND A.STUDENT_ID!=B.STUDENT_ID;
```

Here is the STUDENT table columns:

```
STUDENT_ID primary key
FNAME
LNAME
```

It seems to work. But according to the practice exam, it is worth 15 points so I am not sure if it is totally right. What if there more that two students have the same fname and lname? How would I write it or would this work for that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (which is what you get with those multiple `FROM` clauses) and the duplicate rows that would create, I'd use an `EXISTS` clause

```
SELECT a.STUDENT_ID, a.FNAME, a.LNAME
FROM STUDENT a WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM STUDENT b
  WHERE a.FNAME = b.FNAME
  AND a.LNAME = b.LNAME
  AND a.STUDENT_ID <> b.STUDENT_ID
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75fd6/3

You would also benefit greatly by having an index on both `FNAME` and `LNAME` but I doubt that's going to be relevant to your practice exam.

Comment: Ok so came across another question that i am stuck on how would I make a function based index to improve performance here. There doesn't seem to be any functions to base the index on.

Answer (score 1):

What you have will technically work.  However, the number of rows returned per matched student will equal `n - 1`, where `n` is the number of students who have the same first and last name as the matched student.

To address this, use a `DISTINCT` clause in your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STUDENT_ID
FROM STUDENT A, STUDENT B
WHERE A.FNAME=B.FNAME
    AND A.LNAME=B.LNAME
    AND A.STUDENT_ID!=B.STUDENT_ID;
```